# Pyinstaller with Django on Windows - "environment can only contain strings"

Tags: django, pyinstaller

I'm writing a script that is a simple gui wrapper around the `manage.py runserver` utility of my django set-up. I have been able to package the whole thing together with PyInstaller on OSX just fine; however, when creating the relevant executable on Windows, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: environment can only contain strings
```

After diving into some of the utilities that PyInstaller called to hit this bug, I have revealed that two environment variables have been set to unicode strings: the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and `PYTHONPATH` environment variables.

I could feasibly modify one of the PyInstaller scripts to attempt to re-encode these variables, before they hit the underlying `Popen` that is throwing the error; however, that does not seem tremendously portable.

Is this an issue anyone has encountered before? Are there `spec` settings, or some other such thing, that I should change?

Thanks!

**Edit**

I've attempted to encode any environment variables as I put them in as "ascii," but they still end up getting set as unicode strings. Example:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE".encode("ascii", "ignore"), "DataSite.settings".encode("ascii", "ignore"))
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this issue; it turns out, I was passing unicode strings into the PyInstaller methods for the various `path` variables when I ran it, and those unicode strings ended up poisoning the well down to where they were being stored as environment variables. Surrounding them with the `str()` function worked to solve it.